# What's that peaceful song in Naruto Shippuden episode 54?

Tags: naruto, music

It start at around 7:10 in Naruto Shippuden. It's just so good and why has no one ever made like a tracklist of each episodes' songs alike One Piece' tracklist where you can find anything you heard in any episode of one piece to be able to find the exact name of it.

Does anyone know what that song is called? It starts at 7:10 in Naruto Shippuden episode 54.

Answer (score 0):

Having listened to almost the entirety of the three OST's that naruto shippuden has had released , i did not find what you were asking for . But nevertheless , instead of the name itself i found the tracks for you ,
[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1O04qZv3-4) i found the shorter version , 
and the extended version [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MDRq1x53HRk)

Comment: The first link is correct, but the second link is to an entirely different song. They do sound sort of similar, though.